# 2017-08-16 05:08:54 Convert String to in Date "17-Aug 13 : 30" using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert dateString "2017-08-17 12:08:00" to in "17-Aug 17 : 38" in this format.

```
func timeFromString(dateString : String)  {

    let inFormatter = DateFormatter()

    inFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    //NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    inFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

    let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    outFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM hh:mm"

    let date = inFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
    let outStr = outFormatter.string(from: date)

}
```

I just want to add 5:30 also.

Because date formatter is HH:mm in input? So I am not getting exact output? And if yes, then why?

Comment: *"What should I do?"* – Lookup the documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html has a link to http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns where all patterns are clearly documented. Your input format "dd -MM-yyyy HH:mm" makes no sense for parsing "2017-08-16 05:08:54"

Comment: I know man Documents are there but I am asking because if anyone has done than it's easy to discuss.
Thanks

Comment: I am just little bit confused in format HH: mm and hh:mm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input is **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss** and the output is  **dd-MMM HH:mm**.So do like

```
    let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
    // set the input format
    outFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
    // convert your string to date
    let date = outFormatter.date(from: "2017-08-16 05:08:54")!
    // set the output format 
     outFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM HH : mm"
    // convert your date to expected output string
    let outStr = outFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(outStr) // -> outputs 16-Aug 05 : 08
```

Comment: Why "hh" for the input format if there is no AM/PM in the input string?

Comment: Yeah  I understood. 
Thanks

Comment: OK @MartinR I understood Thanks

Comment: If AM and PM is there ?

Comment: if you used the output dateformat as 12 hour you can use `outFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM hh : mm a"` for AM and PM

Answer (score 1):

The input format should be `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` and the output one - `dd-MMM HH:mm`. You can always check format for iOS in [NSDateFromatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com/)

Comment: Why hh:mm ? not HH:mm

Comment: @kishor0011 you can go to website and find this out at the reference tab ;) don't be lazy

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Date formatting is correct (As per your input string).

Try this:

```
    let inFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let date = inFormatter.date(from: "2017-08-16 05:08:54")!
    inFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM HH:mm"
    let outStr = inFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(outStr) // -> 16-Aug 05:08
```

Comment: why you used the two **DateFormatter()**

Comment: but this one is wrong `"dd-MMM hh:mm"`, questioner needs output in 24 hour format change to this format `"dd-MMM HH:mm"`

Comment: Thanks to help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
 let inFormatter = DateFormatter()

    inFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    inFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

    let outFormatter = DateFormatter()
    outFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    outFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM HH:mm"

    let date = inFormatter.date(from: "2017-08-16 05:08")!
    let outStr = outFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(outStr) // 16-Aug 05:08
```

Comment: why you used the two **DateFormatter()**

Comment: first is for get the date from the string and second one is for get output require to this question you can also set formate in first one

Comment: is not **"dd-MMM HH:MM"** it is **"dd-MMM HH:mm"**

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya: Try your code with input string `"2017-08-16 05:30"`. Can you spot the error?

Comment: Thanks to help me.

Comment: @MartinR yes i got it its return my current date month which i passed 08 so its return 08 the mm is right answer thanks for correcting my answer guys..